# How to Retrieve Deep Link Data in Flutter with Branch.io After App Install?

Tags: flutter, dart, branch, deep-linking

I'm working on integrating Branch.io for deep linking in a Flutter application and have encountered a specific use case that I need help with.

Scenario:
My app uses Branch.io deep links containing specific parameters, including an openId link. The intended behavior is as follows:

[image]

A user clicks on this deep link.
If the app is not installed, the user is redirected to the app store (Google Play or App Store).
After installing the app from the store and opening it for the first time, I need to retrieve the original deep link data, specifically the openId parameter.
Issue:
I am unsure if it's possible with Branch.io in Flutter to retain and access the deep link data after the user installs and opens the app for the first time. How can I achieve this? Is there a specific setup or method in Branch.io and Flutter that allows for the deep link data to be available after the first app launch post-installation?

I have set up Branch.io in my Flutter app and can handle deep links when the app is already installed. However, I am not clear on how to handle the scenario where the deep link is clicked.